# iPhone iOS Core Data should I subclass an abstract entity for my entities?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Currently I have the following data model in my app:
Record is an abstract entity with timestamp, type, name. I have 3 types of entities that subclass Record. My NSFetchedResultsControllers pull Record objects and I sort them by class in my table views:

```
Event1 has record as abstract parent, there will be 10000 such events
Event2 has record as abstract parent, there will be 100 such events
Event3 has record as abstract parent, there will be 100 such events
```

Event 1 is generated by the system, while events 2 and 3 are created by the user.

The intention of this system is so it is easier to display data **when all data** is required.

However, I'm running into an issue where I want to display **only partial data** - user-created events and allow the user to edit them.

**I'm wandering if my current data model is an effective way of filtering and displaying only user events (core data would have to separate only a handful events from the system-generated events). Should I make the system-generated events a separate entity?** Should I even worry about things like this, or is core data optimized enough so stuff like this does not matter?

Below is the NSFetchedResultsController that made me ask this question:

```
          NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

            [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //system-generated events do not have type defined, while user events do have a type
            NSPredicate* predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.type > %0"];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
//^What are the performnance implications of the above predicate?



            // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
            // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
            NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

If all you want are the user events then just use a fetch request on that entity, not the superclass.

Andrew